# Get array key to remove an array based on that array object

Tags: arrays, function, reactjs, arrayobject, array-key

New question, so this is the array

```
[
    0: {
        "id" : "3"
        "name": "David",
        "age": "20"
    },
    1: {
        "id" : "6"
        "name": "",
        "age": "18"
    },
    2: {
        "id" : "8"
        "name": "Micheal",
        "age": "25"
    },
    3: {
        "id" : "9"
        "name": "Wonder Women",
        "age": "20"
    },
    4: {
        "id" : "12"
        "name": "Clark",
        "age": ""
    }
]
```

How to delete based on id when I click a button? In my app have a delete button to delete this array. I think it need to get array key in order to delete the array.

For example: I can get the id=8, but how can i get array key 2 to delete number 2 array?

If you don't understand, please welcome to comment. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this is valid array?

Comment: that just an example. that 1, 2, 3, 4 should not be there

Comment: just for explain purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to directly manipulate the contents of an array instead of returning new array, you can try this

```
let index = array.findIndex(obj => obj.id == objIdToDelete)
if(index != -1) { array.splice(index, 1) }
```

check [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to know more

Comment: As an occasion to remove an element from an array, this is a good way, but be careful when using splice in the react.

Answer (score 3):

```
array.filter((obj) => {
    if (obj.id != yourId){
        return obj;
    }
})
```

and don't forget all commas in your objects in array. (after id)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your array is like:

```
 arr = [
  {"id":"3","name":"Clark"},
  {"id":"6","name":"David"},
  {"id":"8","name":"Miche"}
];

id = 6;

arr = $.grep(arr, function(data, index) {
   return data.id != id
});
```

Now finally this will return array with removing record of id=6

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your array was stored in **obj**, you can use lodash function **remove** to remove an item in an array in the following way.

```
_.remove(obj, function(currentObject) {
    return currentObject.id == "8";
});
```

Which will remove the item '2' containing '8' from your array

Comment: @AlanYong it's a great library to use.